Dryer Thermal Fuse
Is it okay to replace a 250V-10A-150C dryer thermal fuse with a 250V-25A-150C thermal fuse? My dryer is a Maytag PYE2300AYW

No. Not OK.....

Not if you care about safety. How hard is it to order the right fuse?

Downvoters, why so persnickety? This question is fine -- clear, concise, and objective.

@rohmeooo I agree if you voted up as I have then we will have negated the downwards.

I believe the system automatically downvotes the question when some (all?) vote to close reasons are selected. I feel that this question should be closed as the only the manufacturer can know for sure if a non-identical replacement fuse will still provide sufficient protection, but am not voting myself in case someone can give a more definitive answer.

I have reopened his question. While it can obviously be viewed as an equipment use question it also has a crucial design aspect which both others and myself managed to miss. I wrote an answer saying it was unacceptable and then deleted it and wrote my present answer. I believe that this question and answer set is useful for other people with similar queries. I have added a caveat at the end of my answer but I think that it would be possible but exceedingly unlikely for this to apply.

VOTERS before downloading this as a question re replacing a fuse with a higher amperage one please note that this is not a pure case of that. There are complexities which I have hopefully covered in my answer. The comment on my answer reh hybrid devices is useful and I will look into that subsequently.

The safest answer when it comes to safety devices is always to safely replace them with the exact same type (barring a recall change) or a type approved in writing by the OEM. That said, I don't think the totality of Russell's answer is wrong.

Can the question be edited to include a picture of the existing fuse showing the part number? It's not clear what the mounting style is, nor any safety agency listing.

@jsotola  That is quite likel;y to be the case. But, unless you are aware of the specific parts used by this manufacturer, then there is a chance that it is a hyvrid that does thermal fusing and current fusing. I looked up the parts and while I found them on numerous sites none mentioned mode of action (no great surprise.)  The photos appeared to be "normal thermal fuses. They appear to be thermal fuses rather troip and stay open until cooled breakers as some such are.

In this case, despite what I said in my prior answer it is quite probably okay. Being sleep deprived (my excuse :-) ) I focused on the replacement of a fuse with a higher amperage one. For a pure fuse that is almost always extremely unwise.
In this case the current rating is very probably only related to the maximum current that the device should handle. It is very probably but not certainly only a temperature activated device. If so then replacing it with a higher current rated one of the same temperature is acceptable.
It is possible but not likely that the manufacturer has included both current fusing protection and thermal protection in the same device. If this is the case then the 25 amp unit would not offer the same current fusing protection and adding an additional 10 amp standard fuse in series would be advisable. This should probably be slow blow.
Note: I include the comment above of a combined thermal and current protection device for completeness. I am not aware of you ever having seen such a device in many decades of experience.

Obviously not the exact type of device that would be in a dryer, but a little searching shows that hybrid thermal-current protective fuses/breakers certainly exist (https://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses-overcurrent-protection/circuit-breakers/thermal/mini-breaker-mhp). With a big company like Maytag that wants to keep labor costs to an absolute minimum, using a similar, possibly bespoke device like this would not surprise me in the least.

@vir if I can conceive of it then Littelfuse  have probably already made it :-) . No did I covered as possibility in my answer but maybe I should reduce the suggestions re probability. Desperate for sleep. Later

All though answer is true, note that higher current devices heat-sink differently, and exact calibration wrt equipment temperature may change.

I would even recommend against replacing it with an exact replacement part until you know exactly why  the fuse blew.  The blown fuse may or may not be your real problem -- there may be another unresolved problem in your dryer that blew the fuse in the first place.
I certainly would not replace it with a fuse that allows your device to dissipate more than 6 times the power it normally would.  You'd still be temperature-fused to the right temp, but who knows what components on any control boards may just blow.
Big expensive appliances that use a lot of power and get very hot by design probably aren't great things to experiment with.  Call a trained repair  person.
